# MYSQL/PHP Coping an image file (works for txt files but not PNG/JPEG etc)

Tags: mysql, sql, image

I just simply want to copy some image files and store them in a folder...
My code seems to work for txt documents but when I want to copy something else it doesn't work :(

```
    <?php

$ImageLocation = $_POST["ImageLocation"];




//$ImageLocation = '/xampp/htdocs/cw/mysql/images/test.txt';

$ext  = (new SplFileInfo($ImageLocation))->getExtension();




$newFile = "/xampp/htdocs/cw/mysql/images/$ProductName.$ext";



if (!copy($ImageLocation, $newFile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}



?>
```

If anyone could help that would be very handy, ta.

Comment: Also just one image at a time for the moment.

Comment: Fixed it, was me being silly